# Action extension crash on load SIGABRT 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, sigabrt

I have xcode project with a "main app" and an action extension. The main app launches fine and works as intended. 
As soon as I invoke the action extension (via export to in Simulator) it crashes with a "Thread 1: SIGABRT" and this is the only output i get.

```html
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
        0x112ac5efc <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
        0x112ac5f01 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
        0x112ac5f04 <+8>:  syscall 
    ->  0x112ac5f06 <+10>: jae    0x112ac5f10               ; <+20>
        0x112ac5f08 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
        0x112ac5f0b <+15>: jmp    0x112ac07cd               ; cerror_nocancel
        0x112ac5f10 <+20>: retq   
        0x112ac5f11 <+21>: nop    
        0x112ac5f12 <+22>: nop    
        0x112ac5f13 <+23>: nop
```

Now, im aware that this probably is an issue with connections between elements and the viewcontrollers, at least it seems to be the usual issue when experiencing this error. But after I've deleted all the views, and thereby connections, commented out the IBs in my code it still crashes.

Is it possible to have dangling connections somewhere that I've missed?
What am i missing here?

Note: I have cleaned project and deleted derived data, without any luck

---

**UPDATE**
After removing the extension and adding it again I've gotten more information about the crash from Xcode, that for some reason wasn't there before. I called a segue in the viewDidLoad()

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowEpayWindowSegue", sender: self)
```

This was a "push" segue and the view WAS embedded in a navigation controller - however the rootview was probably set correctly. After i changed the segue to **Modal** the problem disappeared.

Hope this can help someone :)

Comment: just try to clean and build or try to check extension , is there any yellow warning related to iboutlet

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I've cleaned and deleted derived data, should have mentioned this in question, so I've added that. There is no outlets or actions in the code atm, all commented out, thus no connectors and no warnings regarding these.

Comment: then if possible upload it to github so that i can check it out whats the exact issue .

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Its not possible, sorry :(